# consts inside classes?

Tags: c++

Hi I was trying to define a constant inside a class, doing it the normal or usual way doesnt seem to work

```
class cat
{
public:

    cat();
    ~cat();


private:

    static const int MAX_VALUE = -99999;
    int Number;


public:

    void OrganizeNumbers();
    void SetNumbers();

};
```

So the solution I found after doing some research was to declare it as `static` but what does this means and also I want to ask it is really necesary to declare a constant, becuase as you can see it is private right? i means it can only be accessed by the class methods so why to set a constant and also I read that using `static` only allows you to use integral type so its actually a dissavantage... if you are thinking to make a game.

Comment: What problem were you trying to solve that brought you to the conclusion that you needed this member to be `static`?

Comment: Allright the class name doesnt have any to do with what it does its just a funny name, the process im trying to achieve is to organize numbers so I need a limit for begining the processes `if(Number[i] < MAX_VALUE)` then we begin with the proccess `if(Number[i] < Number[j])`....

Answer (score 3):

`static` means that the member will be shared across all instances of your object.

If you'd like to be able to have different values of a const member in different instances you'll need to use a initialization list to set it's value inside your constructor.

See the following example:

```
#include <string>

struct Person {
  Person (std::string const& n) 
    : name (n)
  {
    // doing: 'name = n' here is invalid
  }

  std::string const name;
};


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Person a ("Santa Claus");
  Person b ("Bunny the Rabbit");
}
```

**Further reading**

- [[10] Constructors - parashift.com/cpp-faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6)
- [10.1 Construct Initialization List](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/)
- [Initialization Lists in C++](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

Comment: I dont get your example very well I writed it on my cpp file I get errors?

THX for the links..

Comment: @LeandroTheBest Typo from my part, hold on, I usually name my snippet objects `Obj`, now I named it `Person` to make it easier for you to understand, but forgot about it when writing the constructor.. post updated.

Comment: Oh this also worked but when in the same file I dint know Classes could be initialied as soon they were created

Answer (score 2):

1) Declare it "private" if you're only going to use MAX_VALUE inside your class's implementation, declare it under "public" if it's part of your class's interface.

2) Back in "C" days, "static" was used to "hide" a variable from external modules.

There's no longer any need to do this under C++.

The only reason to use "static" in C++ is to make the member class-wide (instead of per-object instance).  That's not the case here - you don't need "static".

3) The "const" should be sufficient for you.

4) An (older-fashioned) alternative is to define a C++ enum (instead of a "const int")

Comment: Well if I only do it by typing const I get errors like uninitialized const etc.... and if I initialize it on cat::cat() I get read only errors?

Comment: @LeandroTheBest Check out my post for how to initialize your const values.

Comment: you have to init it with : `cat() : MAX_VALUE(-99999) {}`

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some confusion of ideas here:

1. A `static` member doesn't have to be an integral type, the disadvantage you mention does not exist.
2. `const` and `private` are unrelated, just because a member can only be accessed from instances of a given class, doesn't mean that nothing is going to change it.

Being const-correct guards against runtime errors that may be caused by a value changing unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

you have to init the `const` attribute in the constructor with :

```
cat() : MAX_VALUE(-99999) {}
```

(which was declare as `const int MAX_VALUE;`)